# Chrome devtools event overlay

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, dom-events

When inspecting my code with Google Chrome Devtools, 
I get this green event overlay on my page.

[image]

Does someone know how to disable these overlays?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the option in chrome devtools that showed the overlay:

In the upperright corner of the devtools panel there's an option to show 
the '**drawer'** panel.

On the **'Rendering'**-tab you can enable/disable **'Show potential scroll bottlenecks'**

[image: devtools screenshot]